# How do I make default System.Convert (to numeric) methods recognize an empty string as zero?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I have some code that parses strings and when a string is empty, exception is thrown. I'd like to make the program still convert empty strings to zero without modifying parsing code. How do I do that?

**UPD:** I know that if I have a few lines of code, I should check the input string with `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, but I have almost a hundred `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToInt16` lines, so I would really like to solve this some other way like writing an extension method or something.

Comment: can you show the code..? empty strings should not throw exceptions normally unless you are doing some odd type of conversion.. have you looked at IsNullOrEmpty ..?

Comment: Let me understand. You want System.Convert.ToInt32("") return 0? Without changing the method name called?

Comment: @DJKRAZE `Convert.ToInt32("")` will throw a FormatException, but `Convert.ToInt32(null)` will return 0. Don't ask me why :)

Comment: you will get an error you can't convert empty string to a Int I would do an if IsNullOrEmpty check if not emtpy or null then convert the string to Int32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ChaosPandion's answer (based on his code) I figured out how to make a fast check and conversion. It also helps reduce code changes to only deleting `Convert.` from them.

Here's the method for int:

```
public static Int32 StringToInt32(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return 0;
    else
        return Convert.ToInt32(str);
}
```

Comment: All `Convert.ToInt32` does is check if `str` is null, returning `0`, otherwise calling `Int32.Parse(str)`, so with that check already in your method you can call `Int32.Parse(str)` directly instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

```
Convert.ToInt32(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr) ? "0" : myStr)
```

Another idea is to use:

```
int res;
Int32.TryParse("", out res);
```

`TryParse` will fail and return false, however `res` will be set to 0 as a result as `out` parameters must be initialized.

You really don't have many options to avoid changing "almost a hundred" instances of `Convert.Int32`.  Using [Steve's extension method technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081890/392044) would be fairly straight forward, but you'd have to go through every call and add the `.EmptyToNumber()` at the end.

You can also do a global *Find and Replace* in Visual Studio and replace `Convert.ToInt32(` with `SafeConvert.ToInt32(` and then implement the static class `SafeConvert` as a wrapper.  That should be fairly safe to do.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done *without* changing the value passed into `Convert.ToInt32` (or the other conversion method with this observed behavior of throwing a `FormatException`).

If it is *just* the empty-string that is causing issues then the ternary conditional operator can be handy:

```
int num = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)
    ? Convert.ToInt32(input)
    : 0;
```

(`Convert.ToInt32(null)` will actually evaluate to 0 just fine, but it is just as valid to handle that case ourselves ..)

Of course this will still break for input values like `"foo"` and whatnot ..

Comment: What if string is not parsable ? for example input="Something"

Comment: @SoneshDabhi See the comment placed at the bottom placed in anticipation of such questions ;-) I would say **then it should be an Exception** (unless the behavior is *really* desired as such ..)

Answer (score 2):

The best thing I can think of is

```
int number = System.Convert.ToInt32("".EmptyToNumber());
```

where EmptyToNumber is an extension method for strings

```
public static string EmptyToNumber(this string input)
{
    return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? "0" : input); 
}
```

this, however, will require a search of all of you Convert.ToInt32 in your code and add the extension EmptyToNumber to the existing string passed as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper course of action here is to apply a different technique rather than expecting the framework to change for you. Try using the following code that will create an extension method for instances of string.

```
public static class ConversionExtensions
{
    public static int? ToInt32(this string input)
    {
        int value;
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            // this is some weird input that 
            // I may need to handle
            return null;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String x = "";
    int val =0;

    if(x != String.Empty){

      if(Integer.TryParse(x)){
         val = Convert.ToInt32(x)
       }else{
         ///Exception
      }
    }

     Use val variable here
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are familiar with RegEx you could do something like the following

```
public static bool IsNumeric(string text)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? false :
            Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^\s*\-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*$");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You say an exception is thrown when the string is empty?  So catch the exception.

```
int myvar = 0;
try {
  myvar = myParseMethod(input); // call your parse method here
}
catch (MyEmptyStringException ex) {
  // Keep going
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this. Always requiring the heavy syntax of a try-catch is not very readable.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Agreed, I wouldn't want to use it everywhere, just wrapped around the main parse routine.